# Cannot edit text in chart exported by Matplotlib and opened in Illustrator

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, adobe-illustrator, eps

I am exporting charts from matplotlib and editing them in Illustrator.  It's great that I can edit the lines, but the text also comes in as lines, so I cannot change fonts, edit text, etc.  I've exported as EPS, PDF, and PS with the same issues.

I'm using matplotlib version 1.0.1 with python 2.7.1 on OSX Snow Leaopard.

I appreciate any insights offered! I tried using pdf2ps as suggested [here](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/2010-06/msg00365.html), but all that did was degrade the quality of the image without making the text rendered as real text. pdftops looked nicer, but still can't edit the text results.

Comment: do you mean that the text is converted to outlines ?

Comment: not outlines. they are converted to vector shapes that, when ungrouped, are individual lines in the shape of each letter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can edit the text in Acrobat/Illustrator if you set `pdf.fonttype` to 42 (TrueType), and export in pdf. You can set this in your `~/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`:

```
pdf.fonttype : 42 # Output Type 3 (Type3) or Type 42 (TrueType)
```

..or dynamically:

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
```

Apparently it defaults to Type3 which Acrobat/Illustrator can't deal with.

Comment: OCR in Acrobat did not work. I mean, it converted the the text while it was open in Acrobat, but after saving and opening in Illustrator, they are not editable as text still...

Comment: Yes, Adobe seemingly cripples Illustator to force you to use Acrobat. Edit text it in Acrobat, or another PDF editor.

Comment: Actually, even using Acrobat, I can copy the text, but can't edit. It (Acrobat) tells me "all or part of the selection has no available system font..."

Comment: actually acrobat derived from illustrator the native format for illustrator is pdf

Comment: @mishaF I played with it today, apparently you can edit the text as long as you set pdf.fonttype to 42

Comment: @zeekay That did it! Thanks so much for figuring that out! I tried the dynamic version of your answer and it worked great.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with `mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`.