# How can I export a matplotlib figure as a vector graphic with editable text fields?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to export multiple plots for editing in Adobe Illustrator and I am trying to make the title, the axis labels, and the bar chart labels as individual text fields. ie if I click on the title in Illustrator (or your editor of choice), the entire title is a field of its own.

Here's how I am exporting as vector graphics without text fields:

```
plt.bar(x_data, y_data)
plt.title('Fancy Title')
plt.xlabel('Informative X label')
plt.ylabel('Felicitous Y label')
plt.draw()
fig.savefig(savepath, bbox_inches='tight', format='svg')
plt.show()
```

This outputs a nice vector graphic, but I can't edit the text as fields. I can run it through a text conversion software, but that moves text ever so slightly and makes everything appear off and leaves font detection up to the software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot edit text in chart exported by Matplotlib and opened in Illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956182/cannot-edit-text-in-chart-exported-by-matplotlib-and-opened-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try these lines:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
mpl.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42
```

In my experience, the default fonttype is not editable, but this one is.

Comment: why 42? are you sure 42 is the answer?

Comment: if 42 is really the answer, are we sure we know what the question is?

Answer (score 6):

You might set the svg fonttype to none:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
```

The following also works:

1. Save the figure as pdf, `plt.savefig("filename.pdf")`
2. Open the pdf in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org),
   i.e. File/Import... then choose the [image] option.
3. Now you can edit the text in Inkscape.
4. (optionally) export the figure from inkscape (e.g. as svg file) to later import it in any other program.